# iis keeps asking for credentials when using hostname but working fine when using localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, localhost, hostname, iis-10

we have a website hosted on local iis and using windows authentification, it works fine when we try to reach it using localhost (http://localhost:56687) but keeps asking for credentials when we use hostname (http://myWebsite)

Comment: Give us something else, screenshot or code from inside the `<web.config>`

Comment: i found the answer here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/896861/you-receive-error-401-1-when-you-browse-a-web-site-that-uses-integrate